# Activate Anaconda virtual environment in Windows 10 - error

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I like to create a virtual environment for my python project. For that, I like to activate my created environment. For that I am doing this command-

```
conda create -n <env_name> python=3.6.* -y #Create environment
conda activate <env_name>
```

After that, I am getting this error-

```
PS C:\Users\abrar> conda activate

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". C:\tools\miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s C:\tools\miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="C:\tools\miniconda3/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^
```

Can anyone please help what I need to do to make my pc able to run `conda activate` command?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Have you tried using the `anconda command prompt`?

Comment: yes, i have tried

Comment: And it was the same error message?